# Gradle Log4j Log Level

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, logging, log4j

Stack Overflow community!

I recently added Gradle support to my project and now have a problem with my logging output. I configured IntelliJ to run and build my project using Gradle, but now I only see logs that are printed to the standard error output stream. My project uses `Apache Log4j 2.0-beta9`.

The Gradle documentation says that logging libraries that use the standard output stream are redirected to the Gradle log level `QUIET`, so I tried two things:

1. Adding `org.gradle.logging.level=debug` to my `gradle.properties`
2. Adding `logging.captureStandardOutput(LogLevel.INFO)` to my `build.gradle.kts`

Both did not work, so I'm asking for help here. Thanks in advance!

---

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    application
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
}

group = "net.inceptioncloud"
version = "1.0.3.0-alpha"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))

    implementation(fileTree("libraries"))
    implementation(fileTree("libraries-minecraft"))
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

logging.captureStandardOutput(LogLevel.INFO)

application {
    mainClassName = "net.minecraft.client.main.Main"
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf(
        "-Djava.library.path=../natives/",
        "-XX:+DisableExplicitGC",
        "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC",
        "-XX:+UseParNewGC",
        "-XX:+UseNUMA",
        "-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled",
        "-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=30",
        "-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=150",
        "-XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary",
        "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit",
        "-XX:+UseBiasedLocking",
        "-XX:SurvivorRatio=8",
        "-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90",
        "-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15",
        "-Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true",
        "-Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates\u00AD=true",
        "-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods",
        "-XX:+UseCompressedOops",
        "-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat",
        "-XX:+AggressiveOpts",
        "-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2048M",
        "-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing",
        "-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=20000",
        "-XX:ParallelGCThreads=10",
        "-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures"
    )
}

tasks {
    run.configure {
        main = "Start"
        workingDir("runtime/")
    }
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += listOf(
            "-Xopt-in=kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi",
            "-Xopt-in=kotlin.contracts.ExperimentalContracts",
            "-Xopt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ObsoleteCoroutinesApi",
            "-Xuse-experimental=kotlin.Experimental"
        )
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileJava {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    }
    compileTestJava {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    }
}
```

**log4j_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="SysOut" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <XMLLayout />
        </Console>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="File" fileName="logs/latest.log" filePattern="logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss}] [%t/%level]: %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <filters>
                <MarkerFilter marker="NETWORK_PACKETS" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
            </filters>
            <AppenderRef ref="SysOut"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: I've tried your config and it seems to work as expected. Have you tried adding a test logging message (println) as per Gradle's docs? Also, do you get a different output when building the project via IntelliJ vs from the command line?

Comment: When adding a test logging message (without log4j) using println(), it is displayed in the console. Also, there is no difference when running it from the command line.